# Creating an empty array of functional interfaces

Tags: java, arrays, functional-interface

I have a method which returns an empty array of `Function<T,V>`

```
public <T, V> Function<T, V>[] foo() {
    ...
    return (Function<T, V>[]) new Object[0];            
    ...
}
```

But I catch `java.lang.ClassCastException` at runtime.
Is it possible to return an empty array of functional interfaces?

Comment: and the main question is: why do you need it?

Comment: @AdamSkywalker imagine I have a method which accepts `Function<T, R>... functions`. And now I need one more method which accepts `R... objects`. So I decide to convert each object (r) in objects into lambda `x -> r` and pass them to an existing method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest thing you can do is

```
return (Function<T, V>[]) new Function[0];
```

This has nothing to do with functional interfaces, and everything to do with arrays and generics not interacting well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast an Object[] to another type, simply because it's not that type. This applies even if the array size is 0.

Why don't you simply return an array of 0 Functions?

```
return new Function[0];
```

This may give an "unchecked cast" warning, but it will still work, since there's no difference at runtime between the type `Function[]` and the parameterized type `Function<T, V>[]` due to type erasure. In this case, you can safely use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: this does not even compile

Comment: @AdamSkywalker thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected it.